# Versioning of WSP package

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Can we keep versioning of WSP package?

If yes then how? I know only components within WSP can be versioned.... but what will be real answer?

Rgds

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to have versioning of wsp-packages, but you have to do that manually. Pick versioning numbers using some of the techniques mentioned in the [Software versioning article of Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning).

You can at any time deploy a previous version of a wsp-package (if you have a solution where feature-deactivation is done the correct way).

Comment: Filenames of WSP's don't matter, only the Solution ID (these days generated by Visual Studio), so you can embed the version number in the filename of the WSP. A manual process like you say but used here for a couple of projects.

Comment: @JamesLove True that! Usually I store my previous releases in different folders with project name and version number. It's not unusual to have PowerShell and SQL scripts within a certain deploy and the wsp name stays the same even if it doesn't matter. Most important is to have versions in some way, even if it's also version controlled by the TFS.

Comment: I've also heard of people putting a text file with the version information inside the package. That way, if the package gets renamed or moved to a different folder, the version information isn't lost.